# converting react router to v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have an error message as so when trying to convert an existing app to use **react-router v6**:

> Error: A `<Route>` is only ever to be used as the child of `<Routes>`
> element, never rendered directly. Please wrap your `<Route>` in a
> `<Routes>`.

here is my `App` component (`BrowserRouter` wraps the app, custom `Router` component is a child):

```
import React from 'react';
import './config';
import './App.css';

import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Router from './auth/route/router';

import Header from './components/header';
// import MobileHeader from './components/header/mobileHeader/MobileHeader';
import Footer from './components/footer';
import { AuthDataProvider } from './auth/AuthDataContext';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <BrowserRouter>

        <AuthDataProvider>
          {/* <MobileHeader /> */}
          <Header />
          <Router />
        </AuthDataProvider>
        <Footer />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`Router` component contains `Routes`, and `Route` as child respectively:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
// import PrivateRoute from './privateRoute';

import CompanyDetailsPage from '../../components/pages/company-details';
import DashboardPage from '../../components/pages/dashboard';
import HomePage from '../../components/pages/home';
import MessagesPage from '../../components/pages/messages';
import MyClientsPage from '../../components/pages/my-clients';
import Privacy from '../../components/pages/privacy';
import ProviderClientsPage from '../../components/pages/provider-clients';
import ProfilePage from '../../components/pages/profile';
import TermsPage from '../../components/pages/terms';
import ServiceDiscoveryPage from '../../components/pages/service-discovery';

import onBoarding from '../../components/pages/onboarding/onBoarding';

function Router(props) {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route exact path='/' element={HomePage} />
      <Route exact path='/privacy' element={Privacy} />
      <Route exact path='/terms' element={TermsPage} />

      <Route {...props} path='/dashboard' element={DashboardPage} />
      <Route {...props} path='/profile' element={ProfilePage} />
      <Route {...props} path='/onboarding' element={onBoarding} />
      <Route
        {...props}
        path='/company-details'
        element={CompanyDetailsPage}
      />
      <Route
        {...props}
        path='/company-clients'
        element={ProviderClientsPage}
      />
      <Route {...props} path='/my-clients' element={MyClientsPage} />
      <Route
        {...props}
        path='/service-discovery'
        element={ServiceDiscoveryPage}
      />
      <Route {...props} path='/messages' element={MessagesPage} />
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default Router;
```

I'm not sure what this error means relative to my architecture. It seems to check out to me, of course I know something is missing somewhere. This is day one for me of ever using router v6 so any and all help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overall structure of `Routes` component to `Route` components is correct, but the routed components should be rendered as JSX, not a reference to a React component, on the `element` prop.

```
function Router(props) {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={<HomePage />} />
      <Route path='/privacy' element={<Privacy />} />
      <Route path='/terms' element={<TermsPage />} />

      <Route {...props} path='/dashboard' element={<DashboardPage />} />
      <Route {...props} path='/profile' element={<ProfilePage />} />
      <Route {...props} path='/onboarding' element={<OnBoarding />} />
      <Route
        {...props}
        path='/company-details'
        element={<CompanyDetailsPage />}
      />
      <Route
        {...props}
        path='/company-clients'
        element={<ProviderClientsPage />}
      />
      <Route {...props} path='/my-clients' element={<MyClientsPage />} />
      <Route
        {...props}
        path='/service-discovery'
        element={<ServiceDiscoveryPage />}
      />
      <Route {...props} path='/messages' element={<MessagesPage />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

Comment: So after converting the components to JSX I am still receiving the same error.

Comment: @BenShekhtman Are you rendering any `Route` components elsewhere in your code? Have you ensured you've killed and restarted any development build watchers/hot reloaders?

Comment: @BenShekhtman Ah, yeah, that'll do it, gotta render all the `Route` components into a `Routes` component, even when they are nested and rendered by children route's components. Cheers.